# mc1322x on Contiki-os, development environment

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, contiki-os

I want to ask if there is ready to run Virtual Machine image anyone to develop on mc1322x microchip on Contiki-os.

Why I ask is this, I'm dealing with this for 3 weeks, and what I advance to take is nothing.

Is there anyone who is experienced in contiki-os - mc1322x agreement?

Comment: mc1322x is well supported with Contiki. What problems are you having exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with [Instant Contiki](http://www.contiki-os.org/start.html).

For specifics on using the mc1322x with Instant Contiki, see [this page](http://mc1322x.devl.org/repos/contiki-mc1322x/cpu/mc1322x/doc/rpl-tutorial.md).

There is a [mc1322x mailing list](http://devl.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/mc1322x) where things like Contiki are occasionally discussed.

Comment: Yeah, I already know about these links and the mailing list. But I cannot see the previous mails in mailing list and cannot install mc1322x library on instant contiki, I even cannot run hello world example.

Comment: There is an archive of previous mails on the list at the link I provided.  And you should just ask on the list if you're still having trouble.  You'll need to provide details of your problems, of course.